# How do I publish/Subscribe AWS IoT - server side using Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-java-sdk

I'm really new with AWS and IoT, and my goal is to:

1. Use the Java SDK v.2 from my serverless application to create/get/update/attach/... certificates and things.
2. Create client side MQTT demo application to connect publish and subscribe to messages used by my new certificates and thing created in phase 1.
3. Publish/subscribe messages in the server side in order to talk to my things/clients.

1 & 2 I've managed to do perfectly.
But I don't understand how should I do the 3rd one.

- Should I use the IoT device SDK as well in the server side ? If so with what credentials do I connect ?
- Is there some objects in the SDK that I've missed?

**In order to connect to IoT Core from the server I first configure my SSO connection using the AWSCLI and in the code I simply use my profile name and region to connect.**

Comment: see the AWS documentation to understand the flow and technology integration required, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html.  This page display a flow diagram of the events,   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-gs.html

Comment: @mzm I've read this article among others, but still don't understand if there is an easy way using AWS SDK to connect to the IoT Core message broker..

Comment: Do I have to create rules and send them to the SQS in order to capture those messages ?

Comment: take as an example, use mobile SDK to create an app on the phone  to send events to AWS IoT infrastructure, of course other third party IoT device are customize to send events to AWS IoT service,  (for a proof of concept it doesn't need to a phone app) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/connect-to-iot.html.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I've already manage to communicate between the client and the server - using  the IOT **Device** SDK. But as a server I would have expected maybe to be above the device and acting like a device.. If there are not ways to do so, It is also an answer for me

Answer (score 1):

Your serverless Java application needs to be configured as a "Thing" in the same account/region as your IoT devices. In the console, go to

AWS IoT -> Manage -> Things

and create a thing for your app. In this case you shouldn't need a "Device Shadow", and you can select "Auto Generate Certificates".

For the IoT Policy, you will need the following :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:client/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your application will communicate with IoTCore using the endpoint shown in the Settings screen in IoTCore for the region where you have created your thing. Your application will authenticate using the key/cert you downloaded when creating the thing (username/password auth is not allowed).

Once your application connects to the endpoint, you will want to "subscribe" to the same topic your devices use to send messages. You can also publish to one or more topics.

In order to debug communications, you can use the MQTT client in the AWS IoTCore console, just note the console needs to be refreshed periodically when communication times out. I recommend marking your topics as favorites so they are easy to re-subscribe to on a refresh.

As for coding in Java, you should be able to leverage examples from the AWS IoT Device SDK here :

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2/tree/main/samples

Here's a link to the MQTT client class :

http://aws-iot-device-sdk-java-docs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/AWSIotMqttClient.html

Please note that your app will not have access to messages when not in use. There are a few strategies to deal with message persistence, but that's outside the scope of your question, so I won't cover it here.

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer.. Creating a Thing for my serverless and give him a superpower policy came to my mind, but I've tried to avoid it and somehow find a way to use my IAM credentials like I'm using with the rest Java SDK. If my only options are to create a Thing or create Rule followed with an Action (SQS, HTTPS,...) then I got my answer and I will have to choose between the cheap and better one..

Comment: Expect the design issue that concerns me, there is another thing (not IoT Thing this time :) ) that worry me. Regarding scaling and persistence. My serverless App will run on the EKS in order to scale and prosses hundred thousands of clients which each sends allot of messages every minute. Can I use this "Server Thing" for all my instances (of the service), when all of them will listen together to the messages from the real things - the clients. Would it work properly?

Comment: Regarding the IAM policy, you aren't granting any super powers, just the ability to communicate with devices over MQTT. Your existing integration (CRUD devices) has more power :-).

With respect to consuming all the MQTT messages from devices, you can do this via an IoT Rule and inject into a database like Dynamo. There is no need to scale your application to consume message, only to give your users access to your app.